# Unstaged and uncommitted changes to files gone after checking out master branch

Tags: git

I really hope someone can help me here. I've Googled and searched on SO endlessly to no avail.

I have a git repo of a project i'm working on. I've been working on many different features, each in a different branch. Today I wanted to change to the master branch and typed the following:

```
git checkout master
```

I got a warning stated that it couldn't change to the branch because I had uncommitted files (none of these files were ones I'd made changes to) so *as a complete idiot* I did the following:

```
git checkout master -f
```

I was shocked to find that `git status` shows absolutely no changed files. Are all my changes gone? When I switch to one of the branches I created, `git status` shows no changes. I had not committed or staged any of the files I made changes to.

I really hope someone can help me, multiple days of work went into the features I was working on.

Comment: After `checkout -f` you can only rely on the software which restores data from your filesystem

Comment: Yeah, take help of your IDE or whatever tool you're using to restore from local history. Git can't help you here, Alas!!

Comment: Do / did you have some changes you *had* staged (without committing)?  And, any work you *did* commit on other branches is easy to recover.  (Hence the general git rule: "commit early and often")

Comment: @torek Unfortunately I hadn't. I will keep this in mind for the future, but it seems all that work is lost, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What `git checkout <branch>` does is that it takes those files that are different between current branch (HEAD) and branch you are switching to, it replaces working area version (and I think also the staging are version) with the version from `<branch>`.  Files that were the same in HEAD and in `<branch>` keep their changes.

But `git checkout -f <branch>` replaces both worktree and the index with the version from the `<branch>`. You are out of luck, unless you have IDE open with unsaved files (and no autorevert), or backup files from IDE, or filesystem restore.

Note that if you *did* `git add` files at some point, you will have some contents of said files in the object database of the repository, and you can try to recover it with the help of `git fsck --unreachable`.

The [git-checkout(1) manpage](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-checkout.html) says:

> `--force`, `-f`
>
> - When switching branches, proceed even if the index or the working tree differs from HEAD. This is used to ***throw away local changes***.